# Bound on a logarithmic integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to give an upper bound to this integral?

I do not even know where to start from when facing this type of exercises. I gave it a try by developping the derivative, but it only gets worse. And neither Mathematica nor Mathlab help.

$$\int_2^x \frac{y}{5\ln^2(y)} \frac{d(\frac{\ln(y-1)}{\ln(y)})}{dy} dy$$

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the correct thing? Just plotting the integrand, it looks positive for $y>2$, so I don't see why the integral should converge to $0$ as $x\to+\infty$ (as you claim in a comment to the answer).

Comment: @mickep Maybe you are right and it does not comverge to 0, but the integral is correctly written. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give an easy upper bound for $x>0$ for part of the integral.  See if you can finish the rest with similar methods.  Expanding the derivative gives, $$\frac{1}{5} \int_2^x\frac{y}{ln^2(y)}[ \frac{1}{(y-1)ln(y)} - \frac{ln(y-1)}{yln^2(y)}].$$  Let's look at the first term first we have, $$\frac{1}{5} \int_2^x\frac{y}{(y-1)ln^3(y)}dy, $$  Since when $y \in [2,x]$ we have that $1-\frac{1}{y} \leq ln(y) $ so $\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{y})^3} \geq \frac{1}{ln^3(y)}. $ So we have for the first term,$$\frac{1}{5} \int_2^x\frac{y}{(y-1)ln^3(y)}dy\leq \frac{1}{5} \int_2^x\frac{y}{(y-1)(1-\frac{1}{y})^3}dy=\frac{1}{5} \int_2^x \frac{y^4}{(y-1)^4}dy\leq\frac{1}{5} \int_2^x y^4=\frac{1}{25}(x^5-32).$$  In the last line I used the inequality  for $\frac{1}{ln^3(y)},$ simplified the integrand, used $\frac{1}{(y-1)^4}\leq 1$ for $y \in[2,x],$ and then integrated.  Do you think you can bound the second term now?

Comment: Thank you! But since when $x \to \infty$ the integral converges to 0, I spected an upper bound that also converged to 0 for big x

Comment: I just wanted to give a simple naive way to get an upperbound, this is definitely not a tight upperbound.  To get a tighter upperbound you could evaluate the integral $\frac{1}{5} \int_2^x \frac{y^4}{(y-1)^4}dy$ although it still wouldn't have the property you're looking for.  I'm not sure how to show it's bounded for large x, sorry!